# weird behavior when running FUSE c++ code

Tags: c++, fuse

I have tried running basic FUSE code in C++.
the code is based on BBFS code, but is very lite:

```
struct fuse_operations oper;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Initialise the operations
    oper.getattr = caching_getattr;
    oper.access = caching_access;
    //... some more here

    int fuse_stat = fuse_main(argc, argv, &oper, NULL);
    return fuse_stat;
}
```

the functions are implemented and only logs to a file their name.

the behavior I see when I run this code is very weird: the application finishes its run, but the FUSE is not running. it behaves the same until I call the 'unmount' from the shell.

at that moment (the system tries to destroy the mount), I see in my log file that the `init()` and `destroy()` functions are called.

any ideas why? is there anything i need to do in order for the `init()` to run immediately?

Comment: Do you flush the log each time you write?

Comment: no, but even if this was the error, I would have seen attempts to call some function other than init() and destroy(), but there are non - even when I tried calling other FUSE functions.

Comment: even more than that, when I try to run 'ls' on the mountdir I get the following error: "cannot access mountdir/: Input/output error".
BTW, I did use the fflush() function and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in the arguments that were sent to the FUSE main function.